# How to have only some constructor parameters injected with Autofac combined with using an InjectionModule

Tags: .net, registration, autofac

**Summary:**

How to combine an injection module with regular `contain.Resolve()` calls in registration?

> **~ Update (5 hours later and after feedback)~ :**
>
> The use of *RegisterType<>* as opposed
>   to *Register()* does not solve the
>   actual complexity level I have in
>   production code, I have updated the
>   demo code on BitBucket to include a generic
>   *ISecond*, with examples of: *IMagic* and *CreateMagic* (interface, class respectively).
>
> The HG repo code has been updated, as
>   has the PasteBin link below.

**Details:**

There is a class with 2 dependencies

```
public SomeClassWithILogDependency(ILog log, ISecond<T> second)
```

*'ILog'* has an InjectionModule defined for it such as, just like in the documentation

( [LogforIntegration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration) ) see bottom of post

If the class has only 1 dependency then this line of Autofac registration works in the simplest scenario:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeClassWithILogDependency>()
.As<IUseILog>()
.PropertiesAutowired();
```

**BUT**

I need to call `container.Resolve<ISecond<T>>()` in the registration for more parameters on the class, but something like this does not work:

```
builder.Register(
    c => new SomeClassWithILogDependency(
        c.Resolve<ILog>(), c.Resolve<ISecond<T>>()))
    .As<IUseILog>()
    .PropertiesAutowired(); //with or without this
```

The `c.Resolve<ILog>()` is the issue as *"that service has not been registered."*

I also tried

```
SomeClassWithILogDependency(c.ResolveOptional<ILog>() //without luck...
```

Any ideas as to what I have missed, or completely different strategy? I hope the solution is not to have more InjectionModules...

Full code posted on [PasteBin.com](http://pastebin.com/yaJYsk7n) as a single file

**Or** entire solution from [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/NickJosevski/autofaclog4netdemo)

> hg clone https://NickJosevski@bitbucket.org/NickJosevski/autofaclog4netdemo

**Injection Module Code (to make this post complete):**

```
public class LogInjectionModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;

        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ILog),
                (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(t))
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: `PropertiesAutowired()` tells Autofac you want it to try and inject dependencies into public, writeable **properties** of `SomeClassWithILogDependency`.  However, your question seems to be about how to get the constructor injection working.  Please can you clarify?

Comment: @bentayloruk thanks for the feedback. I've updated it to be more specific to my objective and not my current path of investigation (which may be the wrong track).

Comment: @Nick-Josevski Following your clarifications, I don't know of anyway to create a registration delegate that references a `ResolveParameter`.  My *hunch* is that you cannot so this and you have to use `RegisterType`.  Therefore, I would also guess that you will have to handle the other parameters in a similar way to how you are handling the ILog injection (i.e. in OnComponentPreparing).  Hopefully Nick or someone will tell us otherwise :)  I am going to delete my answer.

Comment: @bentayloruk thanks for taking a look - much appreciated, it's a tricky situation I've gotten in to here

Comment: @Nick-Josevski Unfortunately, I am out of time to look at this any further.  However, my next port of call would have been to try using `WithParameter(...)` on the `SomeClassWithILogDependency` registration call in order to do the ISecond work.  This should combine the ILog param with your ISecond param  Just a thought.

Comment: @bentayloruk thanks for your help, took me a while to have some time to get back to this problem, but I got it working now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [bentayloruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418492/bentayloruk)'s suggestion, the solution was in fact using:

```
WithParameter(/* ... */)
```

**So the registration code now looks like this:**

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeClassWithILogDependency<IMagic>>()
.As<IUseILog>()
.WithParameter(
    (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == (typeof(ISecond<>)),
    (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISecond<IMagic>>("second")
    );
```

> The sample application has been updated, but **not** the pastebin entry.

**More Info:**

This being a simplified example of my production code, was resolved slightly more easily than my real code, the solution there involved one more specific step of using the concrete type for the ParameterType check, example in this 'domain'

```
pi.ParameterType == (typeof(CreateMagic))
```

The reason being for this is my production *SomeClassWithILogDependency* did not have its generic parameter wrapped with an interface, but I chose to make the sample application showing the issue operate slightly different but yielding the same issue.

```
//demo:
class SomeClassWithILogDependency<TTypeOfISecond> : IUseILog
{
    public SomeClassWithILogDependency(ILog log, ISecond<TTypeOfISecond> second)
}
//-------------- vs --------------
//production:
public class RealClass<TOne, TTwo>, IRealClass<TOne, TTwo>
{
    public RealClass(ILog log, TOne t1, TTwo t2)
}
```